# Can't convert data from datasource to series map in Grafana + Echarts plugins

Tags: javascript, grafana, echarts

I am plotting box-plot using Echarts plugins:
My sample box-plot is here: [Examples - Apache ECharts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-light-velocity&theme=dark)

And my problem is I can't import data into echarts plugins:

My code:

```
data.series.map((s) => {
  if (s.refID === 'DATE_FILTERED') {
    categories_date =
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === 'date').values.buffer ||
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === 'date').values;
  } else if (s.refID === 'VH_CTQ') {
    var_20240102 =
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-02').values.buffer ||
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-02').values;
    var_20240103 =
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-03').values.buffer ||
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-03').values.buffer;
    var_20240104 =
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-04').values.buffer ||
      s.fields.find((f) => f.name === '2024-01-04').values.buffer;
  }

  vh_ctq_data = categories_date.map((id, index) => {
    return {
      value: [categories_date[index]
        , var_20240102[index]
        , var_20240103[index]
        , var_20240104[index]]
    };
  });
  // return categories_date.map((d, i) => [d, var_20240102[i], var_20240103[i], var_20240104[i]]);
});
```

My first query table (VH_CTQ) like:

| 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-03 | 2024-01-04 | 2024-01-05 | 2024-01-06 | 2024-01-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.122 | 1.118 | 1.125 | 1.122 | 1.118 | 1.128 |
| 1.115 | 1.125 | 1.122 | 1.128 | 1.126 | 1.122 |
| 1.127 | 1.118 | 1.114 | 1.109 | 1.134 | 1.128 |
| NULL | 1.118 | 1.124 | 1.104 | 1.114 | NULL |
| NULL | 1.115 | 1.111 | 1.126 | 1.119 | NULL |
| NULL | 1.127 | NULL | NULL | 1.118 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1.106 | NULL |

My second query table (DATE_FILTERED) like:

| date |
| --- |
| 2024-01-02 |
| 2024-01-03 |
| 2024-01-04 |
| 2024-01-05 |
| 2024-01-06 |
| 2024-01-07 |

My question: How can I draw box plot with x-Axis is date column? and if my date column is variable (dynamic) so how can apply that?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be working is to build a dataset object which stores the x-values in the first dimension and boxplot-values in the form `{min: .., Q1: .., median: .., Q3; .., max: ..}`. You can precompute these values with some external library and bring them into the desired form.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-light-velocity&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAmBDMWDOApmAFywDaa6ylVsewArgE4DGBpFttS2Y7sAcgBMABiEAWALQiAjNKECANLAC2EaKQBso5QEUZpABwBWEcpUEMELBtgBOAMxnYuoaTt3nKrAA9SMkU8AX0UaLh4cfmExKVlpByVVdVIAdk1nfSMRL0trW0NxDLdYQ09zX3dTELDuXijRCWk5EXFEtVsUspcDEuNjc1ybI01-l2LDQy8K-2zqrlgAXTCgygXQ9B8AQR8IPFJUWjAATxAoyAslMPaASWg-JgA3LAAbf2yRWAAqWHSvn4_vhJlPN0AB6UF0XDQbBMDCwc4EWBMAj0Z4MSAwWDqJLPZ67AgsGAYPBhXy7AAyWAARgRXtR5gAzYBMbxge6kARII5HIKSJAAWX5vJ4GCCl3meAAFsAAO783yUml0sBMBgEdZUFboOawI7bXb7HWEJgQFEcMIHLjHU4cqnAHwgZ7AMDiri8fBEW4YAh-WAfEEBwPg2CgDHQF7LVYoIIAbiAA):

```js
option = {
  dataset: [
    {
      source: [
        {date: '2024-01-02', min: 620, Q1: 850, median: 930, Q2: 990, max: 1090},
        {date: '2024-01-03', min: 760, Q1: 800, median: 840, Q2: 890, max: 950},
        {date: '2024-01-04', min: 790, Q1: 855, median: 865, Q2: 880, max: 900},
      ]
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    minInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,          // standard time resolution in milliseconds
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: '{yy}-{MM}-{dd}',
      showMaxLabel: true,
    }
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'boxplot',
      datasetIndex: 0                       // optional
    }
  ]
};
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use the built in boxplot transform together with the `itemNameFormatter` attribute to set names based on the index.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-light-velocity&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygUwjAvDA2gcgEwAMeALALQECM5eOANDPkWZeQMx0OEnlUHEeNuLAgFYBXZrwBs4pj3IB2HAF0A3ACh1IAA5QAluAwwA3upjwkCCMigAubGfMnHTmBBABXAE7Bk9rC6uQa5YABwiBPQKxJEwAJwEsRQECrFxrLHhaRH0caFp-fShhTDJibkl6bFSOTAKUpnJ9GVJiWkNuQ3KtIHBwVhxHfExnWkjMMWZ5RO1k7nToeOhGVEJRU0TJXMTKxPTCmt1Q_kE3b19IdtXW0MKhFH3MFKPoUNxqbmzlRtZRR8TSyWs0BmRiZwuFzCh1CPx-L32_3qsWiyNqSNyGziL2hxxKd1BmVmaPy4Ih_VC0PGCi2G3RE1p0LhhMy_1CrNpS0x4ziswWP1SynOwUFrgAvj1XKZglAvAhIAAzEBeAC29ilfSgAE9tH4GAAjEAAD20ABsQFA6EKYKAwPK9ABzNUwPQoZUAOQQyuQADElcqkCgvPYABTaBCy5UQACUGAAfBYUBAsGGIxAAHQANwQJo8yGUMFFrgA9EWYAAedCVzBeZAm5BZsCwADCIDgyHOosC4scpMNAEFDXoIGrAlqdfYcMAkMh7UrNZbzN3zJqB0O1Uu3MgvHpUP5AurXGPdTgDcazRaJUFEFArDYAJJgNuG-wULuXwWi1RAA):

```js
const dates = ['2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04', '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07'];

option = {
  dataset: [
    {
      source: [
                [850, 740, 900, 1070, 930, 850, 950, 980, 980, 880, 1000, 980, 930, 650, 760, 810, 1000, 1000, 960, 960],
                [960, 940, 960, 940, 880, 800, 850, 880, 900, 840, 830, 790, 810, 880, 880, 830, 800, 790, 760, 800],
                [880, 880, 880, 860, 720, 720, 620, 860, 970, 950, 880, 910, 850, 870, 840, 840, 850, 840, 840, 840],
                [890, 810, 810, 820, 800, 770, 760, 740, 750, 760, 910, 920, 890, 860, 880, 720, 840, 850, 850, 780],
                [890, 840, 780, 810, 760, 810, 790, 810, 820, 850, 870, 870, 810, 740, 810, 940, 950, 800, 810, 870]
            ]
    },
    {
      transform: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        config: { itemNameFormatter: (params) => dates[params.value] }    // <==== relevant Code
      }
    },
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'boxplot',
      datasetIndex: 1
    },
  ]
};
```